# Refresh Div on page load then auto refresh every X seconds

Tags: jquery, refresh

I have a div that I would like to refresh on page load then auto refresh every 60 seconds after. I have it set now to refresh every 60 seconds but I don't know how to combine that with the first page load. Here is the whole php page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var notify = $("#notify");
    notify.hide();
    notify.click(function(event) {
        // Handle the click on the notify div so the document click doesn't close it
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    var count = $("#count");
    var notifyLink = $("#notify_link");

    count.click(showNotification);
    notifyLink.click(showNotification);

    function showNotification(event) {
        $(this).unbind('click', showNotification);

        $(this).addClass("selected");
        loadData();

        notify.show();

        $(document).click(hideNotification);

        // So the document doesn't immediately handle this same click event
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    function hideNotification(event) {
        $(document).unbind('click', hideNotification);

        notify.hide();
        notifyLink.removeClass("selected");
        count.removeClass("selected");

        notifyLink.click(showNotification);
        count.click(showNotification);
    }

    count.load(
        "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
    );
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        count.load(
            "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
        );
    }, 60000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});

function loadData() {
    $('#loader').html(
        '<?php echo elgg_view('ajax/loader',array('slashes' => true)); ?>'
    );
    $("#result").load(
        "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/data.php",
        function () {
            $('#loader').empty(); // remove the loading gif
        }
    );
}

</script>
```

Comment: Let's lose the PHP; it's not relevant. Make a testcase.

Comment: What do you mean "lose the PHP"

Comment: I mean, get rid of it from your question. Let's deal with just the Javascript that it generates. You should already have done that as part of your debugging.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok its gone.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess I don't get what you mean.  why is that important?

Comment: Isolating a problem is a crucial step in debugging, and a critical life skill. It's especially easy when you have a comms boundary. If you'd done it, this question would probably not have had to be posted!

Comment: (Until you do, you don't know whether the problem is with your PHP or with your Javascript, and that adds needless complexity. If the problem can be reproduced with the PHP-less generated Javascript, then you just _vastly_ narrowed down the problem, and also saved us from having to ask repeated follow-up questions from afar.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand what "problem isolation" is and how its used in troubleshooting.  The problem in this case is there is no problem.  If I had a light that didn't work I would start at the light bulb, then the switch, then the wire and so on.  In this case the light works I just need it to come on right when someone enters the room instead of after 60 seconds of someone entering the room.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not really. I have no idea why PHP is involved in a client-side Javascript task.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because those are the data files that the function is loading.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you please help with those php files still in it?

Comment: For the purpose of the question, the PHP input can be completely removed and replaced with some hard-coded test input string within the Javascript. You said you understand problem isolation, but that you didn't do this as one of your first debugging steps makes me question such an assertion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh Div on page load then auto refresh every 60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648879/refresh-div-on-page-load-then-auto-refresh-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the

`count.load(
            "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
        );`

on the page load. With jQuery you could do something like this (put the code in a function, as Anthony pointed out):

```
$(function() {
    function loadCount() {
        count.load(
            "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
        );
    }

    // Load on page load (call the function loadCount):
    loadCount()

    // Set the refresh interval and call the function loadCount every 60 seconds):
    var refreshId = setInterval(loadCount, 60000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Good idea!  I don't know why but it didn't work.  Ive update the question to show all Ive done.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or something that can help us to track the problem?

Comment: Well, I just tried your code (correction: I tried your code without the PHP tags and I put all your code inside a proper html file), and I do see a hyphen (the link with the ID "notify_link") and nothing else (as expected). When I click on it, the div with the ID "notify" is showing up/hides and the setInterval parts also works. :-)

Comment: I have now edited my first code and added a function that is called instead (as Anthony pointed out below).

Comment: If it did work, and you first accepted it, why did you unaccept it?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm new to the site and didn't know what i was doing.  thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

On page load do it once, and then do your setInterval.

```
function loadCount() {
    count.load(
            "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
    );
}

$(function () {
    var refreshId = setInterval( function () {
            loadCount();
        }, 60000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
}
```

Edited based on suggestion to make the code more maintainable.

Comment: It makes more sense to make it an actual function, call that on page load, then pass the function reference to the `setInterval()` call. That way you only have to make changes in one place, rather than two, and you're not unnecessarily duplicating code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist disregard last comment.  how would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is correct -- using setInterval should work as expected. I wrote a quick test that just uses console.log() and it works. But I think your error is in your .load() function in loadData() -- you aren't using double quotes so `'<?php echo elgg_view('ajax/loader',array('slashes' => true)); ?>'` gets interpreted as three separate strings. What you want is `"<?php echo elgg_view('ajax/loader',array('slashes' => true)); ?>"` (surrounded by double quotes).

Comment: @ YXY Ive added the double quotes and it still takes 60 seconds for the div to load.  I need it to load immediately on page load and refresh every 60 seconds after.

Comment: Ive added the double quotes and it still takes 60 seconds for the div to load. I need it to load immediately on page load and refresh every 60 seconds after.

Comment: -1: Utter nonsense. The Javascript and PHP are executed in completely different contexts; there is no way for those quotes to conflict.